# What evidence is there for each side of the debate over the authenticity of "Exit Through The Gift Shop"?

Tags: character, exit-through-the-gift-shop

I recently watched "Exit Through The Gift Shop" and thought it was absolutely excellent.  After the movie was over, my friend told me that a lot of people think that Bansky invented the character of Mr. Brainwash.  Apparently there is a lot of supporting evidence for this claim, and a lot of counter-evidence; however, I have been unable to find a complete resource, merely patchwork commentary and criticism in a variety of locations.  Can anyone summarize all the arguments and claims for each side of the debate?

Comment: It's a great movie either way and possibly a better movie if it retains the ambiguity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I firmly believe that Thierry Guetta is not a real person but was invented for the film. Some evidence:

- he reportedly made lots of money from his clothing business, but in the brief clip of his store, it looks like a couple of racks of clothes in some crappy room
- he reportedly has a wife and kids, but then leaves them to spend "years" filming his documentary
- all 'Thierry Guetta' or 'Mr Brainwash' material found via Google seems manufactured, not authentic. For example, mrbrainwash.com seems real at first glance, but try to buy something... you can't!
- Bansky delights in trickery
- the creation of the Guetta character would be an ideal way to spice up what is otherwise just a documentary about Banksy and his fellow street artists

Comment: Agreed that Thierry Guetta/Mr Brainwash is _not a real person_ (even though I heard that the actor _is_ actually related to Space Invader, as narrated). However: am I the only one that believes that _this guy is actually Banksy_!? When he's at his house and describes **how they met** (Guetta and Banksy) he just claps his hands and laughs. Seems fake (on purpose perhaps), funny, and simply central piece of this play of "**lets just lift the 4th wall** for a micro-second".

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia's [entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_through_the_gift_shop#Reception_and_hoax_speculation) has a nice summary on the speculations:

> The film received overwhelmingly positive reviews, holding 96% on
>   Rotten Tomatoes, and was nominated for Best Documentary in the 2011
>   Academy Awards.[5][6] One consistent theme in the reviews was the
>   authenticity of the film: Was the film just an elaborate ruse on
>   Banksy's part, or did Guetta really evolve into Mr. Brainwash
>   overnight? The Boston Globe movie reviewer Ty Burr found it to be
>   quite entertaining and awarded it four stars. He dismissed the notion
>   of the film being a "put on" saying "I’m not buying it; for one thing,
>   this story’s too good, too weirdly rich, to be made up. For another,
>   the movie’s gently amused scorn lands on everyone."[7] Roger Ebert
>   gave it 3.5 stars out of 4, starting his review saying that "The
>   widespread speculation that Exit Through the Gift Shop is a hoax only
>   adds to its fascination."[8] However, in an interview with
>   SuicideGirls,[9] filmmakers Jaimie D'Cruz and Chris King denied that
>   it was a hoax, and expressed their growing frustration with the
>   speculation that it was: "For a while we all thought that was quite
>   funny, but it went on for so long. It was a bit disappointing when it
>   became basically accepted as fact, that it was all just a silly hoax
>   ... I felt it was a shame that the whole thing was going to be
>   dismissed like that really - because we knew it was true."[10]
>
> The New York Times movie reviewer Jeannette Catsoulis wrote that the
>   film could be a new subgenre, a "prankumentary".[11]
>
> New York Film Critics Online bestowed its Best Documentary Award on
>   the film in 2010. French journalist Marjolaine Gout gave it 4 stars
>   out of 5, linking Mr. Brainwash and Jeff Koons and criticizing Thierry
>   Guetta's art as toilet papering.[12]

Comment: Well, there's obviously more evidence than just that.  The Wikipeia entry doesn't present any actual evidence that it might be a hoax other than a hunch.